# How to load C# winform strings from resource file without rebuild

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, resources, .net-cf-3.5

I have an application developed on .NET CF 3.5 and I try to localize it for multiple languages. I have made a global resource file that is under Properties folder and moved all strings from code and forms to the resource file. What I want to do is to have one resource file. I will translate the file and deploy on each device. But the problem is: if I change the resource file and run the application without rebuild I still see old resources. What I missed to do? 
I set resource file build action to Embedded resource.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Localization.aspx

This article discusses how to handle your problem, by using two different approaches.

Option A discusses how to create a sattelite assembly containing a localized version of an embedded resource. This is most likely what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you, this article was helpfull

Answer (score 0):

See if you wish to embed these resources, by selecting Resource -> Properties and Embed Resource. That way, seperate resources files will not be created. Its all bundled.

Comment: He does *not* want it embedded. He wants it separate.