# To get a list of all control text/caption of a Visual Studio solution

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, visual-studio-2010, excel

I have a `VS Solution` in that my project contains something around 160 Forms. Now I want to get the Control's `text` property from all the forms.

Why I want to do is my application is in English Language. My client asked me to convert the whole software into other languages also. Now he wants me to provide him list of all menu and other controls in a Excel or XML sheet from where he will translate everything.

SO is there any mechanism available which can read all of my forms and its control and save `text/caption` of every item in a external file or may be in any medium.

Is it possible. Looking for fellow support. Regards.

**ADD1:**

Like I have a MDI form and its designer contains `this.mnu_recycle.Text = "Recycle";`

Likeways we have `n` number of `.Text` items. I just want a list of all of them.

Comment: Well there is nothing built in to do that. But you could code something. form.controls impelents IEnumerable, so you can loop through with foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create some code that creates an instance of each form then loops through all the controls getting the text and name of the control. Write the info (Form name, control name, control text) to a csv file or generate a resource file which can be translated. You can then write a small app to change the form code files to use resource files.

Programmatically creating a resource file
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542.aspx

Resource files will make your application be easier to translate to other languages take a look at these

[C#: How to bind the text of a winforms button to a resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322484/c-how-to-bind-the-text-of-a-winforms-button-to-a-resource)

[What would be the easiest way to generate new localized resource files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704115/what-would-be-the-easiest-way-to-generate-new-localized-resource-files)

[How to load C# winform strings from resource file without rebuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358831/how-to-load-c-sharp-winform-strings-from-resource-file-without-rebuild)

Comment: That's not what he wants. Read the question

Comment: Yeah, you're right though I'd read in there that he wanted to know of a way to help make his application easier to localize in the future. Check the edit. Thanks

Comment: Now it's ok, but please avoid link only answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers